# How can I properly display my divs in masonry style using flex?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create display divs in a masonry style using flex/flexbox.  It must be a maximum of 2 columns.  Each div have the same width (so it would split into 2 columns evenly), but the the height varies depending on the content of the div.  So some height will be smaller than others.

Straight to the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfmqh.png

The blue boxes are my divs (child) with content in each one of them.  You can notice that they have same width and some have smaller height than others.

**Problem:**  There's a LARGE gap between the top and bottom child on the left column.  The bottom child should move up to the bottom of the top child.  How can I do this?

EDIT:

Here is the CSS in use:

```
#main {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.divBob {
   -webkit-flex: 1;  /* Safari 6.1+ */
   -ms-flex: 1;  /* IE 10 */    
   flex: 0 1 auto;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #CCE0FF;
   margin: 5px;
   width: 45%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: #F0F3FA;//#F9FBFF;
}

.divBob:nth-child(2n+1) {
   clear: right;   
}
```

Comment: `flexbox` can't do masonry style layouts unless you use actual columns instead of rows.

Comment: I can do columns, then that would bring me to another question, how can I split up the children divs in half?  Like, let's say I have 10 child divs, they all sit in 1 column, how can I split it in half so 5 are on the left column and 5 are on the right column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason it has to be with flexbox?

If you don't mind using an alternative method [this tutorial](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/) will show you exactly how to create masonry-style layouts. [Here's what you'll end up with](http://w3bits.com/labs/css-masonry/).

The demo markup is as follows:

```
<div class="masonry">
   <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
   <div class="item">Neque, vitae, fugiat, libero corrupti officiis sint facilis tempora quidem repudiandae praesentium odit similique adipisci aut.</div>
   <div class="item">Incidunt sit unde minima in nostrum?</div>
   <div class="item">Ducimus, voluptates, modi, delectus animi maiores consequuntur repellat quisquam fugiat eum possimus enim culpa totam praesentium magni quae!</div>
   <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dicta dolore adipisci hic ipsam velit deleniti possimus cumque accusantium rerum quibusdam.</div>
   <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae, praesentium consequatur ducimus commodi quam ex illo omnis dicta reiciendis vel nesciunt deserunt aut sequi nam mollitia perferendis ipsam possimus temporibus!</div>
   <div class="item">Ab, adipisci, temporibus eaque quis harum perferendis incidunt cupiditate doloribus dolor numquam voluptates ipsum dolore aspernatur et voluptate ipsam beatae animi culpa.</div>
</div>
```

We make use of the CSS properties `column-count` and `column-gap` which are applied to the parent element to determine the number of columns in your layout:

```
.masonry { /* Masonry container */
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;
}
```

you then need to apply this style to each child:

```
.item { /* Masonry bricks or child elements */
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The tutorial also provides a link to a [JS fallback](http://masonry.desandro.com/) for older browsers

and that's all you need to create a Masonry-style layout :)